# Add array element during definition based on condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I define an array like this:

```
[{foo:0}, true === false && { foobar:1}, {bar:2}]
```

My expected result would be that the middle item is not added at all when the middle condition is not met:

```
[ { foo: 0 }, { bar: 2 } ]
```

in fact it adds false as an array item:

```
[ { foo: 0 }, false, { bar: 2 } ]
```

Is there a way to prevent adding the `false` while maintaining this lightweight syntax (I know I could always use push or the spread operator)

Comment: Nope, there's no such syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: But if you want to keep your building terse you could just `filter` after: `[{foo:0}, true === false && { foobar:1}, {bar:2}].filter(Boolean)`

Comment: You could use a ternary like `condition ? { foobar:1} : null` and filter out `null` values at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `concat` with spread syntax and an empty array as neutral value.

```js
var a = [].concat(...[
        { foo: 0 },
        true === false ? { foobar: 1 } : [],
        { bar: 2 }
    ]);

console.log(a);
```

With apply

```js
var a = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], [
        { foo: 0 },
        true === false ? { foobar: 1 } : [],
        { bar: 2 }
    ]);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Denys suggested, you could do this:

```js
const arr = [{foo:0}, true === false && { foobar:1}, {bar:2}].filter(el => el !== false);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `el => el !== false`? Please make it less verbose.

Comment: Less verbose? What do you suggest, `!!el`? Sorry, but the OP only wants to remove `false` values, nor `0`, `null` or empty strings.